# Changes in census tracts

Tags: qgis, census, brazil

I am doing an analysis using census tracts from São Paulo, Brazil, with Qgis. The problem is that changes in their boundaries occur between the periods. Most of them divide in two or three. The literature usually says that we have to use a something called "minimum comparable areas", creating the smaller area possible and adding the attributes of the tracts that are inside this area to this new one. If the census tract remains unchanged between the periods, by example, this area corresponds to the minimum comparable area, and the attributes are his own.

[image: This is the first year]

[image: this is the first, with the clear lines of the second one]

Is there a way to do that procedure with two or more layers more automatically than one by one?

Comment: I removed your tag for Python because you make no mention of that in your question and have not included a code attempt.